# How to separate the parts of this unix command to use in Python subprocess module?

Tags: python, linux

I would like to add a Linux command to my Python script (using the `subprocess` module). This is the command I would like to add:

`awk '/^>/ {printf("%s%s\t",(N>0?"\n":""),$0);N++;next;} {printf("%s",$0);} END {printf("\n");}' < input.fa`

And this is currently what my code looks like:

```
out = subprocess.Popen(["awk '/^>/ {printf("%s%s\t",(N>0?"\n":""),$0);N++;next;} {printf("%s",$0);} END {printf("\n");}' < input.fa"], 
stdout = subprocess.PIPE,
stderr = subprocess.STDOUT)

stdout, stderr = out.communicate()
print(stdout)
print(stderr)
```

However, it appears that my syntax is wrong somewhere. In some other examples I have seen, it seems like the command needs to be split into sections with apostrophes - however, this command is quite complex, and I do not know where the splitting would be required.

I would appreciate any help in identifying the underlying issue and correcting the syntax of this script.

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to circumvent my problem by using a command which does the same thing but does not include any "\n", which is what seems to have been the cause of my issues. Also, using different quotation marks (i.e. " and ') helps to prevent this causing issues. The code now looks like this and does what I need it to do:

```
print(subprocess.Popen('perl -ne "chomp;print;" chr11', shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE).stdout.read())
```